# All the zeroes of analytic $f$ in $A$ are isolated, or $f \equiv 0$ on $A$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ analytic on an open connected domain $A$. I need to prove that all the zeroes of $f$ in $A$ are isolated, or $f \equiv 0$ on $A$.

What I did: I let $B=$ the set of limit points of zeroes in $A$ and proved that it is closed. If I prove that it is also open, I am done. Any help on this step?

Comment: Use the fact that holomorphic functions have power series expansions.

Comment: More details please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $p$ is a limit point of some sequence of zeros $\{z_n\}$ of $f$. Because $f$ is holomorphic, we can expand it in a power series in a small open disk around $p$. Assume, for the sake of contradiction, that $f$ is not identically zero in the disk. In this disk, we have, for some $n$,
$$f(z)=(z-p)^n g(z),$$
where $g(z)$ is a holomorphic function satisfying $g(p)\neq 0$. This equality implies that $g(z_n)=0$ for all $n$, so taking the limit and using the fact that $g$ is continuous gives $g(p)=0$, a contradiction.